# This is a React app. When I am trying to download a pdf from local folder, I am not able to download

Tags: javascript, reactjs, error-handling

I have this code where I have a large number of books to display in my website.
These books are stored in my local react folder (Ebooks > src > assets > books > bookName.pdf). These can be accessed from a component (Books.js) by "../../assets/books/bookName.pdf".

Now I got a problem that i am not able to download my books when i click on download button(anchor tag).

When I hover over the Download button the I could see a redirected link showing path "localhost:3000/assets/books/bookName.pdf".

I tried importing book manually "import PythonBook from '../../assets/books/PythonBook.pdf";
and a download button "download". This worked.
But I have 100 books to be displayed.

I want to download books when I click on the download button.
What should i do?

//React Component
// Books.js

import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
export default function Books() {

```
const [books, setBooks] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
    const importBooks = async () => {
        try {
            const bookContext = require.context("../../assets/books", false, /\.pdf$/);

            const bookFiles = bookContext.keys().map((filename, index) => {
                console.log('File path:', filename);
                const title = filename.replace(/^\.\/|NotesForProfessionals/g, '').replace(/\.pdf$/, '');
                return {
                    id: index + 1,
                    title,
                    author: "goalkicker",
                    download_link: `../../assets/books/${filename.replace(/^\.\//, '')}`, // Remove the leading "./"
                };
            });

            console.log('Books:', bookFiles);
            setBooks(bookFiles);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error importing books:', error);
        }
    };


    importBooks();
}, []);

return (
    <>
        <div className="books_container" id="books_container">
            <header>Explore Books</header>
            
            <div className="books">
                {books.map(book => (
                    <div className="book_bg" key={book.id}>
                        <div className="book">
                            <p className="book_title">{book.title}</p>
                            <p className="author">by {book.author}</p>
                            <a
                                download
                                href={book.download_link}
                                className="download_btn download_link"
                            >
                                Download
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                ))}
            </div>
        </div>
    </>
);
```

}

Answer (score 2):

I think you'll have to dynamically import each pdf.

try

```
const download_link = (await import(`../../assets/books/${filename.replace(/^\.\//, '')}`)).default;
return {
  id: index + 1,
  title,
  author: "goalkicker",
  download_link,
};
```

Comment: Thankyou. It worked

Answer (score 1):

Import each book and pass it using `book.default`

```
const bookFiles = bookContext.keys().map((filename, index) => {
    console.log('File path:', filename);
    const title = filename.replace(/^\.\/|NotesForProfessionals/g, '').replace(/\.pdf$/, '');
    const book = require(`../../assets/books/${filename.replace(/^\.\//, '')}`);
    return {
        id: index + 1,
        title,
        author: "goalkicker",
        download_link: book.default, 
    };
});
```